# Chrome Apps UX guidelines

Tags: google-cast, google-chrome-app, design-guidelines

In the [Google Cast SDK Overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJItrPj7Ivk) video published on YouTube by Google, the presenter says

> There are design implications that are driven from the Design Checklist so in addition to the platform specific guidelines for Android, iOS and Chrome, it is important to do a thorough review of the Google Cast Design Checklist.

The sentence reads like legal-speak, but more importantly, it mentions existence of **platform specific design guidelines for Chrome**. I never knew that there is anything like that. I attempted googling around, I could find guidelines for [Android](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html), [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/design/index.html), but nothing for Chrome. Does anybody know where the Chrome guidelines can be found?

Comment: I suspect he meant Chromecast, not Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

The design checklist is here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist

The starting point for Chromecast developer doc is here: https://developers.google.com/cast/

Comment: That is not what I am asking for. I edited the the question. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: Ah, sorry my brain jumped right to Chromecast.  Is this what you're looking for -> http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide.html? If so I'll update my answer.

Comment: No. That page is just an API reference. They talk about design a little bit at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/a11y.html but other than that it is only about coding, not UX/UI design.

Comment: I found https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/articles/thinking_in_web_apps , but it feels outdated (especially in the tone it is written in —good old 2010, suffices to say) and too general. The Android and iOS guidelines are more practical, this just gives a grand vision. Also it predates the efforts of putting Chrome Apps on smart phones.

Comment: The presenter was probably just covering all of the bases.  His main point was to review the Google Cast Design Checklist.

Comment: There is a Chromium bug which discusses unified design for Extension Options pages http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25317

Answer (score 1):

There is an unified design guide for both Android and Web Apps that was announced on June 25 2014 at the Google I/O keynote. It is available at the https://www.google.com/design/ site. Regarding Google endorsed UI frameworks, there are two. Polymer Paper and Google Web Starter Kit. Additionally, there are stylesheets on GitHub from various people that aim to replicate the look and feel of the Chrome Settings page as well as various widely-used opinionated Responsive CSS Frameworks that can provide design clues, most notably Twitter Bootstrap and Foundation.

### Polymer Paper

[Polymer Paper](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/material.html) is a set of Polymer Web Components which implements the unified mobile and web UI concept called Material Design. Some of the distinctive characteristics is the use of drop shadows and animated transitions to hide latency and give feeling of responsiveness. The components are built with the Polymer framework on top of web components, so it works best in cutting edge browsers.

### Google Web Starter Kit

Together with the [Google Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/) developer guide the [Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/starter-kit/) provides a starting point regarding look and feel for your web app ([a style guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/resources/styleguide/) with UI elements, e.g. sandwich sidebar), as well as preconfigured selection of helper tools to better manage your CSS styles, minify resources, keep performance considerations in mind and so on. The Starter Kit employs production ready tools and procedures that can be used today.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like that, the presenter probably just misspoke. The [Thinking in Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/articles/thinking_in_web_apps) page on Google Developers could give you some hints, but it feels outdated in many aspects.¨

Just some more general advice on that:

People tend to gravitate towards Twitter Bootstrap these days, so base your design on that and you will play well with others.

Watch the trends and adopt what the big players are using. For example, the sliding drawer on the side seems to be big now.

Regarding the ongoing effort by Google to allow easy porting of Chrome Apps to mobile phones, looking at the Android and iOS guides may help. Most importantly try to optimize your app for touch, avoiding hover, right clicking and minimize the need to type.